# Using anti_join and saving "anti_joined" data to top of a csv file

Tags: r

I am trying to write something which will continuously update a csv file.

There can be some overlaps since my script collects a little more data than is required so I want to use `anti_join` to find the data points which are not in the current saved `.csv` file. I want to append the new data points to the top of the `.csv` file.

Currently what I have is something like:

```
iris = iris %>% 
  mutate(rowId = row_number())
df1 = iris[1:15, ]
df2 = iris[1:10, ]
df1 %>% 
  anti_join(df2, by = "rowId")

  #write.csv(., append = TRUE)
```

Which gives me correctly the missing data (by `rowId`)

```
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species rowId
1          5.4         3.7          1.5         0.2  setosa    11
2          4.8         3.4          1.6         0.2  setosa    12
3          4.8         3.0          1.4         0.1  setosa    13
4          4.3         3.0          1.1         0.1  setosa    14
5          5.8         4.0          1.2         0.2  setosa    15
```

I want to append this top the original data `df1` using `write_csv`. However, my current method adds the data to the bottom of the `.csv` file. I could `sort` the data but when the data set gets really large, sorting the data each time just to append correctly 5 observations at the top of the `.csv` file is not computationally feasible (i.e. when there are 1,000,000 observations, to sort all 1,000,005 observations to have the 5 at the top)

How can I use `dply` / `tidyverse` to append the rows to the top of the data?

Comment: Do you need `df1 %>% 
anti_join(df2, by = "rowId") %>% bind_rows(df1)`

Comment: I thought about that, but it gives me a `df` of 20 observations - the 15 original + 5 duplicates (from the anti_join).

Comment: how many observations are you seeking?  The above code gives 20 rows

Comment: `df2` contains 10 rows, `df1` contains 15 rows (the first 10 and 15 rows of the `iris` dataset). I want to use `anti_join` to find the rows that are in `df1` which are not found in `df2`. (So in this example it will just return exactly `df1` 15 observations. But I want the 5 observations that the `anti_join` collected at the top of the dataframe. (or `write_csv(append = TRUE...)`)

Comment: I am collected data through a function and just appending the newly collected data to the old data - this updates say every hour and I have then a time-series of data (new observations I want at the top of the `.csv` file.

Comment: I corrected it.

Comment: Maybe you want `anti_join(df1, df2, by = "rowId") %>% bind_rows(intersect(df1, df2))`

Comment: Yes, I think that is what I want, I will quickly try it with the actual data now

Comment: Or may also do `rows_upsert(rows_delete(df1, df2, by = "rowId"), df2, by = "rowId")`

Comment: If it's always just one ID column, won't it be easier to use `!rowId %in% df2$rowId` (or vice-versa)?